# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'concurrent'

Tags: python

Buen día,

Tengo un problema con python, estaba intentando publicar e instalar un paquete y al desinstalarlo algo sucedió, ahora cada que ejecuto algún comando de `pip` (Cualquier comando) me aparece el siguiente error

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'concurrent'
```

Esto es lo que devuelve la consola

```
PS C:\Python39> pip --version
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python39\lib\runpy.py", line 197, in _run_module_as_main
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
  File "C:\Python39\lib\runpy.py", line 87, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\pip\__main__.py", line 29, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli.main import main as _main
  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\cli\main.py", line 9, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli.autocompletion import autocomplete
  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\cli\autocompletion.py", line 10, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli.main_parser import create_main_parser
  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\cli\main_parser.py", line 8, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli import cmdoptions
  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\cli\cmdoptions.py", line 23, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli.parser import ConfigOptionParser
  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\cli\parser.py", line 12, in <module>
    from pip._internal.configuration import Configuration, ConfigurationError
  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\configuration.py", line 26, in <module>
    from pip._internal.utils.logging import getLogger
  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\utils\logging.py", line 27, in <module>
    from pip._internal.utils.misc import ensure_dir
  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\utils\misc.py", line 35, in <module>
    from pip._vendor.tenacity import retry, stop_after_delay, wait_fixed
  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\tenacity\__init__.py", line 26, in <module>
    from concurrent import futures
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'concurrent'
```

Ya intenté volver a instalar `pip` con `python get-pip.py` pero también devuelve errores

```
PS C:\Python39> python get-pip.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python39\get-pip.py", line 33324, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Python39\get-pip.py", line 135, in main
    bootstrap(tmpdir=tmpdir)
  File "C:\Python39\get-pip.py", line 111, in bootstrap
    monkeypatch_for_cert(tmpdir)
  File "C:\Python39\get-pip.py", line 92, in monkeypatch_for_cert
    from pip._internal.commands.install import InstallCommand
  File "<frozen zipimport>", line 259, in load_module
  File "C:\Users\NombreUsuario\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp7jtyl813\pip.zip\pip\_internal\commands\__init__.py", line 9, in <module>
  File "<frozen zipimport>", line 259, in load_module
  File "C:\Users\NombreUsuario\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp7jtyl813\pip.zip\pip\_internal\cli\base_command.py", line 15, in <module>
  File "<frozen zipimport>", line 259, in load_module
  File "C:\Users\NombreUsuario\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp7jtyl813\pip.zip\pip\_internal\cli\cmdoptions.py", line 23, in <module>
  File "<frozen zipimport>", line 259, in load_module
  File "C:\Users\NombreUsuario\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp7jtyl813\pip.zip\pip\_internal\cli\parser.py", line 12, in <module>
  File "<frozen zipimport>", line 259, in load_module
  File "C:\Users\NombreUsuario\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp7jtyl813\pip.zip\pip\_internal\configuration.py", line 26, in <module>
  File "<frozen zipimport>", line 259, in load_module
  File "C:\Users\NombreUsuario\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp7jtyl813\pip.zip\pip\_internal\utils\logging.py", line 27, in <module>
  File "<frozen zipimport>", line 259, in load_module
  File "C:\Users\NombreUsuario\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp7jtyl813\pip.zip\pip\_internal\utils\misc.py", line 35, in <module>
  File "<frozen zipimport>", line 259, in load_module
  File "C:\Users\NombreUsuario\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp7jtyl813\pip.zip\pip\_vendor\tenacity\__init__.py", line 26, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'concurrent'
```

También intenté con `python -m ensurepip` y devuelve los siguientes errores

```
PS C:\Python39> python -m ensurepip
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 6, in <module>
  File "C:\Python39\lib\runpy.py", line 210, in run_module
    return _run_module_code(code, init_globals, run_name, mod_spec)
  File "C:\Python39\lib\runpy.py", line 97, in _run_module_code
    _run_code(code, mod_globals, init_globals,
  File "C:\Python39\lib\runpy.py", line 87, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Users\NombreUsuario\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpss9bvr7_\pip-21.2.3-py3-none-any.whl\pip\__main__.py", line 29, in <module>
  File "<frozen zipimport>", line 259, in load_module
  File "C:\Users\NombreUsuario\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpss9bvr7_\pip-21.2.3-py3-none-any.whl\pip\_internal\cli\main.py", line 9, in <module>
  File "<frozen zipimport>", line 259, in load_module
  File "C:\Users\NombreUsuario\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpss9bvr7_\pip-21.2.3-py3-none-any.whl\pip\_internal\cli\autocompletion.py", line 10, in <module>
  File "<frozen zipimport>", line 259, in load_module
  File "C:\Users\NombreUsuario\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpss9bvr7_\pip-21.2.3-py3-none-any.whl\pip\_internal\cli\main_parser.py", line 8, in <module>
  File "<frozen zipimport>", line 259, in load_module
  File "C:\Users\NombreUsuario\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpss9bvr7_\pip-21.2.3-py3-none-any.whl\pip\_internal\cli\cmdoptions.py", line 23, in <module>
  File "<frozen zipimport>", line 259, in load_module
  File "C:\Users\NombreUsuario\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpss9bvr7_\pip-21.2.3-py3-none-any.whl\pip\_internal\cli\parser.py", line 12, in <module>
  File "<frozen zipimport>", line 259, in load_module
  File "C:\Users\NombreUsuario\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpss9bvr7_\pip-21.2.3-py3-none-any.whl\pip\_internal\configuration.py", line 27, in <module>
  File "<frozen zipimport>", line 259, in load_module
  File "C:\Users\NombreUsuario\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpss9bvr7_\pip-21.2.3-py3-none-any.whl\pip\_internal\utils\misc.py", line 38, in <module>
  File "<frozen zipimport>", line 259, in load_module
  File "C:\Users\NombreUsuario\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpss9bvr7_\pip-21.2.3-py3-none-any.whl\pip\_vendor\tenacity\__init__.py", line 26, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'concurrent'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python39\lib\runpy.py", line 197, in _run_module_as_main
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
  File "C:\Python39\lib\runpy.py", line 87, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Python39\lib\ensurepip\__main__.py", line 5, in <module>
    sys.exit(ensurepip._main())
  File "C:\Python39\lib\ensurepip\__init__.py", line 210, in _main
    return _bootstrap(
  File "C:\Python39\lib\ensurepip\__init__.py", line 129, in _bootstrap
    return _run_pip(args + [p[0] for p in _PROJECTS], additional_paths)
  File "C:\Python39\lib\ensurepip\__init__.py", line 38, in _run_pip
    return subprocess.run([sys.executable, "-c", code], check=True).returncode
  File "C:\Python39\lib\subprocess.py", line 528, in run
    raise CalledProcessError(retcode, process.args,
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['C:\\Users\\NombreUsuario\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39\\python.exe', '-c', '\nimport runpy\nimport sys\nsys.path = [\'C:\\\\Users\\\\NombreUsuario\\\\AppData\\\\Local\\\\Temp\\\\tmpss9bvr7_\\\\setuptools-57.4.0-py3-none-any.whl\', \'C:\\\\Users\\\\NombreUsuario\\\\AppData\\\\Local\\\\Temp\\\\tmpss9bvr7_\\\\pip-21.2.3-py3-none-any.whl\'] + sys.path\nsys.argv[1:] = [\'install\', \'--no-cache-dir\', \'--no-index\', \'--find-links\', \'C:\\\\Users\\\\NombreUsuario\\\\AppData\\\\Local\\\\Temp\\\\tmpss9bvr7_\', \'setuptools\', \'pip\']\nrunpy.run_module("pip", run_name="__main__", alter_sys=True)\n']' returned non-zero exit status 1.
```

¿Qué es lo que puedo hacer para que funcione nuevamente?

Comment: Por lo que dicen aquí: https://pythonmana.com/2022/02/202202210319536651.html es probable que quizás la carpeta `concurrent` haya desaparecido de `C:\Python39\lib` y tengas que volver a ponerla (o quizás nunca ha existido). Suerte!

Comment: @masterguru, Efectivamente ese era el problema, tuve que copiar concurrent de otra versión de python y funcionó, pero por más que busco no encuentro artículos que expliquen por qué se borra esa carpeta si yo nunca la borré

Comment: Perfecto, me alegro que te haya servido :-)  En cuanto a porque se ha borrado ni idea, no uso windows por eso, jeje, le pasan cosas muy raras e inexplicables, y encuentro que su explorador de archivos es muy sensible a cualquier intrusión de cualquier sobrino árduo de mover el raton, je... quizas si la buscas a nivel global la encuentras en otra parte movida sin querer. Saludos!